# Accessing the ALAssetsGroup information for an ALAsset object

Tags: ios, alasset, assetslibrary

It's common to enumerate the `ALAssetsGroup` to get the `ALAsset` objects, like this way:

```
[assetGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@",result);              
}];
```

But I have a special use case, which is accessing the `ALAssetsGroup` information for an specific `ALAsset` object. How to do this by avoid enumerating the whole library? Thanks!

Comment: Why? What makes you think you can or that the asset is in only 1 group? Enumerate and build the list yourself.

Comment: @Wain I think you are right: the assumption that `ALAsset` is in only 1 group is wrong. But I have a requirement that is displaying the current user selected `ALAsset` amount for each `ALAssetsGroup` cell in an album picker.

Comment: So enumerate and count...